# Why does 'git status' run filters?

Tags: git

I need to clone a git repo into an existing directory (`$HOME`, for managing dotfiles). I'm doing a bare clone and reconfiguring it because I need to clone into an existing *unclean* working directory. **It works**, however I find that `git status` tries to run filters on first use. Why does it do that and how can I prevent it?

Try this:

```
# create a test repo
mkdir test && cd test
git init
echo hello > hello.txt
git add .
git commit -m 1
echo 'hello.txt filter=foo diff=bar' > .gitattributes
git add .
git commit -m 2

# clone it bare and configure it
mkdir ../test2 && cd ../test2
git clone --bare ../test .git
git config core.bare false
git config core.logallrefupdates true
git reset
git checkout .
git config filter.foo.clean foo
git config filter.foo.smudge foo
git config diff.bar.textconv bar
```

This borks

```
$ git status
error: cannot run foo: No such file or directory
error: cannot fork to run external filter 'foo'
error: external filter 'foo' failed
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

This doesn't

```
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Also, initially doing `git status` multiple times in quick succession (i.e. `git status; git status; git status)` can yield multiple failures. Sometimes.

As far as I can confirm by [much reading](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/ch00/filters_a), the filters should only run when checking files in and out.

So why does `git status` run them?

Comment: what is your `git --version`?

Comment: git version 2.11.0

Comment: Incidentally, I wouldn't (and don't) manage dot-files this way. Instead, I have a Git directory named `Dotfiles` in my home directory, which is an ordinary non-bare tree, and then I symlink `.whatever` to `Dotfiles/whatever`.

Comment: Yes I know, but I wanted to try and do it without symlinking. And it works, including `git-crypt` for sensitive files, except for this little problem :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idea that filters only run during checkin/checkout is something of a [white lie](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/white-lie).  It's meant to make filters more explicable.

In fact, though, filters run when moving files between the index and work-tree (and also, in sufficiently modern versions of Git, when requested with `--path=` options in `git show` and `git cat-file` and `git hash-object` as well: some of these are transitions directly from repository to stdout, or stdin to repository).  This is *mostly* equivalent to checkin/checkout time.  But `git status` has special dispensation as well, due to the cache aspect of the index.

For performance reasons, Git wants to know whether any file in the work-tree might be "dirty" with respect to the version in the index.  Git assumes that the `stat` value `st_mtime`, which typically has one-second resolution,<sup>1</sup> can be used for this purpose: if the `st_mtime` time of the *file*—the work-tree entry—is *older than* a saved `st_mtime` in an index entry, then the index entry is up to date and is "clean": what's in the index matches what's in the work-tree, after applying clean filters etc.

If the time stamp of the work-tree entry is *newer than* the saved index entry, then the file has definitely been modified: the index entry *may* be out of date.  It's not *guaranteed* out of date, as the work-tree file may have been modified in a way that ultimately made no change.  But it's clearly necessary to run the clean filter (and any CR/LF line ending hackery).

If the two time stamps are *the same*, the work-tree entry is indeterminate.  (Git calls this "racily clean" although "racily dirty" would be equally accurate.)

In all these cases, `git status` will run the clean filter (and any input-to-Git direction CR/LF modifications) over the work-tree file to compute a new hash.  If the new hash matches the index hash, Git can and will update the index entry to mark the file as "actually clean".  Now, the next time you do something, Git won't have to run the clean filter.

Unless, that is, you do it all within the resolution of the `st_mtime` stat field.  In that case, the index entry winds up "racily clean" and Git has to try again.  This is what you are observing here.

(Note, by the way, that `git status` runs *two* diffs: one from `HEAD` to index, and one from index to work-tree.  It's that second diff that benefits hugely from the cache aspect of the index.  The index can now also store information about *uncached* files and directories, too!)

---

<sup>1</sup>Some `stat` calls give sub-second precision, but for various reasons, the index / cache entry only stores the 1-second resolution time stamp anyway, normally.

For (much) more on this, see [the `racy-git.txt` file in the technical documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/racy-git.txt).

Comment: Great explanation! It also explains why `touch hello.txt` makes  `git status` run the filters. And it explains why they run again if the time between the file timestamp changing and the status check is too short (<1s). Given this explanation, I would assume there is no way to prevent the filters from running (in my case, the filters will fail until a crypto key is provided). In which case, Is my work-around `sleep 1 && git status &>/dev/null` the best I can hope for...?

Comment: That workaround should work.  I don't know why you're encrypting these things in the first place, though.

Comment: private keys, API keys, etc. I only crypt the things that are sensitive, on a per file basis.

Comment: Ah. Since I symlink specific dot-files I get to be more selective and not Git-ize some things.