# How to make git status consider the clean filter

Tags: git

I am using a clean filter to reset some values that change automatically but I do not want to commit them.
The clean filter works fine in the way that `git diff` does not list the changes and `git add` only adds the patches that are not reset by the clean filter.
However, the file still shows up in `git status` as modified.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41935511/3919733), the filter should be run by `git status`.

I noticed that the file does not show up in `git status` if only a few variables are changed and reset, but it is shown if more is changed and reset.

While I would also like to know if and when `git status` executes a filter, my main question is: How can I get `git status` to always run the file through the filter and thereby exclude it from the modified list?

I do not mind any performance problems or additional parameters supplied to the `git status` call.

Comment: Indeed, the filter *should* be run if needed and the index's time-stamps should get updated. This code in Git is probably a bit fragile though. I wonder if it depends on how long your filter takes to run.